# ORDER BY CASE with wildcard

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
 | id | name | price | number |
 ---------------------------
 | 4  | fr-1 | 1,00  |  9984  |
 | 5  | fr-2 | 5,20  |  5421  |
 | 6  | fr-3 | 3,40  |  7845  |
 | 7  | de-1 | 6,20  |  9494  |
 | 8  | de-3 | 3,80  |  1254  |
 | 9  | de-6 | 3,90  |  3197  |
```

I'd like to sort these like so: (obviously this is wrong, but it hopefully shows what I'm trying to achieve)

```
 ORDER BY CASE
 WHEN name LIKE 'fr-%' THEN name
 WHEN name LIKE 'de-%' THEN price
 END ASC;
```

I would expect this result:

```
 FRENCH PRODUCT
 name: fr-1  |  price: 1,00
 name: fr-2  |  price: 5,20
 name: fr-3  |  price: 3,40

 GERMAN PRODUCT
 name: de-3  |  price: 3,80
 name: de-6  |  price: 3,90
 name: de-1  |  price: 6,20
```

Comment: What would be your expected result from the given data ?

Comment: I will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE
            WHEN name LIKE 'fr-%' THEN 0
            WHEN name LIKE 'de-%' THEN 1
         END ASC,
         CASE
            WHEN name LIKE 'fr-%' THEN name
            WHEN name LIKE 'de-%' THEN price
         END ASC;
```

`'fr-%'` like records will come first, followed by `'de-%'` records. Then, the first group will be ordered by `name`, whereas the second will be ordered by `price`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba2b2/2)

Comment: Wow. It works like a charm! Thank you! I see that I had the beginning right. I am just learning mysql and have been struggling with this quite some time. Could you maybe help me with my learning by explaining me in layman's terms why this extra CASE block you added before is needed ?

Comment: @Bsch1987 The first `CASE` expression ensures that `'fr-%'` like records will come first, followed by `'de-%'` records. It creates, so to speak, two groups of records, the first group is assigned number `0`, second group number `1`.